# Header logo image shows at home page but not others

Tags: magento

I'm using Mgto 1702 with hellowired template. I have various stores that follow the subfolder method (www.domaian.com/store). The header image logo and the Alt text file is in its folder. When you visit www.domain.com/store1 or /store2, etc the right logo appears on the home site header. When I click on any link to change pages (for example, a product page) the header shows correctly but NOT the image.

The header.phtml file includes an If that asks if it's the Home page (getIsHomePage()):?> but that doesn't really matter. I placed the code outside the If clause and the problem persists. I added a "trick" echo clause to follow the behaviour in all cases. The text appears but not the JPG.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Found the solution. It was quite simple actually. I have to force the folder to use the root ("/"). For some reason it works without it for the home page but not the others.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php // if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
<h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
<?php /*else:?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
<?php endif */?>
```

please remove the condition as shown above in the header.phtml page to get the same header in all the pages.